# Dimensionality problem: Input 0 of layer is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 100, 100, 3), found shape=(None, 1, 100, 100, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying make a very basic CNN model for the detection of weeds and differentiate them from crops. I am getting the same dimensionality error each and every time I try and execute the code.

```
IMG_SIZE = 100
def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES: 

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  

        
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):         
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                    new_array = new_array.reshape(32, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3) 
                    training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
           
create_training_data()
```

Preprocessing for the images.

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_20 (Conv2D)          (None, 100, 100, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPoolin  (None, 50, 50, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_21 (Conv2D)          (None, 50, 50, 32)        9248      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPoolin  (None, 25, 25, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 dropout_10 (Dropout)        (None, 25, 25, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 flatten_10 (Flatten)        (None, 20000)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_20 (Dense)            (None, 128)               2560128   
                                                                 
 dense_21 (Dense)            (None, 2)                 258       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2,570,530
Trainable params: 2,570,530
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

(1049, 1, 100, 100, 3)
(1049,)
(1049, 1, 100, 100, 3)
(1049,)
```

Why does my x_train and x_test have all the images? Also, what is that '1' in the middle of the shape? I am assuming that is what is causing the code to crash. I don't really know what that means.

I tried to shrink the dimensions but I do not really know how to. This is the first time I have come across this problem and really don't know how to proceed. From what I have seen, all of the solutions aim towards the dimension expansion but this is the reverse.

What is that random 1 in the shape and how can I remove it?

Comment: Something is wrong with the shape of `X_train`. Can you show the code where you defined it?

Answer (score 0):

The above error indicates that the input data shape is not matching with the defined input_shape of the model.
Please use `tf.squeeze()` for both training and testing input data which will remove dimensions of size 1 from the shape of a tensor and try running your code again

```
X_train = tf.squeeze(X_train)
X_train.shape
```

Output:

```
TensorShape([1049, 100, 100, 3])
```